# How to find the phase of a complex-valued function not in trigonometric form?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following function:

$$(1 + (jw/w_i)^2 - 2j\alpha_i(w/w_i))\over(1 + (jw/w_i)^2 + 2j\alpha_i(w/w_i))$$

I know that the magnitude is 1 since this is a ratio of complex conjugates, but how can I find the phase? I know this involves finding the polar-form representation of this signal, but I'm no sure how to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument (i.e., phase) of $(a+i b)/(a-i b)$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ is

$$ 2 \arctan{\frac{b}{a}}$$

I assume that your $j = i$.  Then the phase of your expression is

$$-2 \arctan{\left [\frac{2 \alpha_i (\omega/\omega_i)}{1-(\omega/\omega_i)^2} \right ]}$$